# Create a new matrix in each for loop iteration

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I'd like to use a for loop to create a new matrix in each iteration of the loop.

```
mining_t = c("Zr_t","Sr_t","Rb_t","Zn_t","Cu_t","Fe_t","Mn_t","V_t","Ti_t","Ca_t","K_t","Ba_t")

for (i in mining_t){
  ??=matrix(c(VI9A_mn[1:7,i],VI9A_mn[8:14,i],VI9A_mn[15:21,i]),nrow=7,byrow=FALSE)
  colnames(i)=c("45","90","135")
}
```

I'd like each matrix to have 3 columns of 7 rows. Each new matrix is made from the ith column (all rows) of the matrix `VI9A_mn` and should have the name of the associated element of the vector `mining_t`.

Comment: It is better not to create multiple objects in the global enviornment, instead work in a `list` as showed in the answer posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a `split` by column of 'VI9A_mn'

```
lst <- lapply(split(VI9A_mn, col(VI9A_mn)), 
                matrix, ncol=3, dimnames = list(NULL, c(45, 90, 135)))
```

It is better to keep the `matrix` objects in a `list`.  But, if we insist to have multiple objects in global environment, use `list2env`

```
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Nice, thx! And is there a way i can call each element of the list by an other name (the name that are in my vector "mining_t)?

Comment: @jo.H  You can use `lst[[1]]` or `lst$Zr_t` to call the an element or `lst[[mining_t[1]]]`